# In Mobile App automation, Eclipse displayed error "Unable to create new remote session."

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, automation, appium

In Mobile App automation, Eclipse displayed error "Unable to create new remote session."

Here is my code :

```
public class MyFirstAppiumClass {

    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException
    {               
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //cap.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion","6.0.1");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus 5");
        cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement> (new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCal() throws Exception
    {
        WebElement two = driver.findElement(By.name("4"));
        two.click();
        WebElement plus = driver.findElement(By.name("+"));
        plus.click();
        WebElement four = driver.findElement(By.name("4"));
        four.click();
        WebElement equalto = driver.findElement(By.name("="));
        equalto.click();
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        WebElement results = driver.findElement(By.tagName("EditText"));
        assert results.getText().equals("8"):"Actual Value is : "+results.getText()+" did not match with expected value: 8";
    }

}
```

And Here is the Error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session.
desired capabilities = Capabilities [{appPackage=com.android.calculator2, appActivity=com.android.calculator2.Calculator, platformVersion=6.0.1, platformName=Android, deviceName=Nexus 5}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

Comment: did you start appium server manually before you start running the code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the below line:

driver = new AndroidDriver (new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

to

driver = new AndroidDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

Comment: Nope, It didnt worked for me. Same issue displaying.

Comment: Thanks it helped me.